# HELM : Adjust container request memory dynamically based on JAVA JVM

Tags: java, jvm, kubernetes-helm

Most of the time, developers forget to sync two values.

`Situation 1: App memory less then allocated  Jave APP1 - -Xmx 100M but Pod level request memory 200M`

Situation 2: Developers forgot to update k8 YAML
`Jave APP 2 - -Xmx 250M but Pod level requests memory 200M`

Just wonder how this situation can be automated. Helm chart will automatically detect -Xms and adjust in helm chat request memory.

Comment: can't believe that is developer responsibility: the final goal is to tell JVM how much memory it may consume, and there are two options: either read about [MaxRAMFraction MaxRAMPercentage](https://dzone.com/articles/best-practices-java-memory-arguments-for-container) parameters or implement *smart* entrypoint which will compute target JVM parameters based on the environment.

Comment: Not sure whose responsibility, but our developers are managing both values. It's pretty overhead for them. Searching solutions on how to automate this process.

Comment: Have a look at the template functions: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/ -- you should be able to derive the heap size and pod memory request from the same value.

Comment: Java has known about container memory limits for a while (see for example [this somewhat dated Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/java-on-container-like-a-pro)) and you shouldn't set `java -Xmx` at all.  The JVM will honor the Kubernetes memory limits and use them to set its heap size.